# Why do I get segmentation fault on trying to compare two strings?

Tags: c, pointers

I was working on an assignment for a simple assembler that should recognize arbitrary variable names like high programming languages. I tried to use Dynamic allocation to an array of char pointers

I am just trying to make an extensible array of strings and being able to search this array for specific strings But it gives a segmentation fault on the line of trying to compare the two strings [line: 14]

```
Comp(&buffer[1], Variables[i];
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define Comp(a,b)  strcmp(a,b) == 0 ? 1 : 0

char buffer[255], **Variables;
int VariableIndex;

void A_instructionHandler() {
    int A_Operand, test = 0;
    if (buffer[0]== '@') { 
        for (int i = 0; i <= VariableIndex; i++) {
            test = Comp(&buffer[1], Variables[i]);
            if (test) { 
                A_Operand = i + 16; 
                break;
            }   
        }   
    }   
}

int main(int argumentCounter, char *arguments[]) { 
    strcpy(buffer, "@variable");
    Variables = (char **)calloc(VariableIndex + 1, sizeof(char**));
        A_instructionHandler();
}
```

Comment: Instead of talking about your code, just show it. It's less effort and communicates more. Add comments to the code if necessary.

Comment: That `calloc` allocates space for *one* pointer. `pointers[0]` is valid. Everything else is not. That should also be `sizeof(char*)` as it's not an array of `char**` but `char*`, though that's just a minor quibble as pointers are pointers. In other cases it can be a big deal, so it's good to match them, or use `sizeof(*pointers)` so you can't miss.

Comment: @tadman It's containing a lot of printfs so I thought showing all this wouldn't be a good idea

Comment: You can and should trim it down, but turning it into a diary entry is a little counter-productive. There's a lot missing from here, we'd prefer a [minimal, complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to use as a basis for a solution.

Comment: What is `VariableIndex`? Is `i` walking off the end of the allocation for `pointers`? Do you ever allocate the entries in the `pointers` array? There's a lot of questions about what's going on in the gaps here.

Comment: Show us the smallest piece of complete, compilable code that segfaults. We can then explain why that code segfaults. Right now, we can't see the actual code that segfaults because we can't see what types the variables are or how they get their values. We need *complete* code that can reproduce your fault.

Comment: @tadman alright Now Everything is here just without the declaration and pritnfs

Comment: In other words, everything is here.. except what's not. *"complete, compilable code that segfaults"* means we can copy, paste, compile, and run what you post, and *only* what you post, feeding whatever input *you* specify is required as part of your question text, and produce your problem.

Comment: Are you trying to make an extensible array?

Comment: @tadman yes exactly

Comment: There's patterns for that, so you may want to look at writing a proper allocation/reallocation function with a sizing feature.

Comment: @tadman I made the code from scratch and this is the minimum that produce the fault

Comment: You didn't initialize `VariableIndex` or any pointers in the buffer you allocated for `Variables`.

Comment: I did initialize VariableIndex sorry just forget to add in the modified code but it's not the problem

Comment: @MahmoudSalah `Comp(&buffer[1], Variables[i])` Where is `Variables[i]` initialized to something other than `NULL`?

Comment: @dxiv
Nope, It's not It's supposed to be empty in the beginning and then starts to add 

. So what I expecting is that comp just returns zero on comparing a null with buffer[1] But it just gives a segmentation fault

Comment: @MahmoudSalah Your expectation was wrong, see [the `strcmp` documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp).

Comment: @dxiv Lol Yes that was the problem thanks so much..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's that code refactored into something more idiomatic:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void instruction_handler(char* buffer, char** variables) {
  switch (buffer[0]) {
    case '@':
      // This iterates over the NULL terminated array by stopping when
      // it hits a NULL pointer, or in other words *v is false.
      for (char **v = variables; *v; ++v) {
        // If this matches a variable name...
        if (!strcmp(*v, &buffer[1])) {
          // Variable matched, so show some debugging code
          printf("Found variable: %s\n", *v);
          return;
        }
      }
  }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[] ) {
  // Create a simple NULL-terminated array of arbitrary size
  char *variables[] = {
    "variable",
    NULL
  };

  instruction_handler("@variable", variables);
}
```

Where that `variables` array can be defined however you like, extended, shrunk, so long as the NULL terminator remains in place at the end.

Some tips based on your original code:

- Don't use global variables unless you have an extremely compelling reason. No such reason existed here.
- Make your functions clear in intent and purpose.
- Pick a naming convention and stick to it.
- Use C conventions like `strcmp()` and just deal with how weird it is, don't wrap that in a `#define` and invent your own C dialect nobody understands. You'll get used to C over time, it won't bother you as much, and you can code without driving other people on your team up the wall.
- Explanations like `argc` expanded to `argumentCounter` is better expressed as a comment than an awkwardly long variable name, especially one that's very non-standard. Comments are great. Use them as much as you like!